# left join query in posgresql running slow

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

Below is the query I ran for more than 12 hours and yet no result, I had to cancel. Earlier, it used to be completed in less than 10 mins. I've checked the execution plan and looks good too.

Query:

```
insert into APT_ADHOC_DISH_UNIQ_SRC_AAMIR(email,decile,segment,cass_suite,last_line,file ) 
select a.email,a.decile,'Green',a.cass_suite,a.last_line,'NEW'  
from apt_custdod_dish_trt_u_deciles_aamir    a 
  left join APT_ADHOC_DISH_SRC_TABLE_AAMIR b on a.email=b.email 
  left join DISH_PREVIOUS_RECORDS c on a.md5hash=c.md5hash 
where c.md5hash is null 
 and  b.email is null 
order by  random() limit  2315108 ;
```

Query Plan:

```
                                                                            QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Insert on apt_adhoc_dish_uniq_src_aamir  (cost=31854466.07..31883404.92 rows=2315108 width=229)
   ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT*"  (cost=31854466.07..31883404.92 rows=2315108 width=229)
         ->  Limit  (cost=31854466.07..31860253.84 rows=2315108 width=109)
               ->  Sort  (cost=31854466.07..31940398.62 rows=34373023 width=109)
                     Sort Key: (random())
                     ->  Hash Anti Join  (cost=10424.64..21560078.86 rows=34373023 width=109)
                           Hash Cond: ((a.email)::text = (b.email)::text)
                           ->  Merge Anti Join  (cost=522.16..20491390.52 rows=34415656 width=37)
                                 Merge Cond: ((a.md5hash)::text = (c.md5hash)::text)
                                 ->  Index Scan using md5_1 on apt_custdod_dish_trt_u_deciles_aamir a  (cost=0.57..8465757.97 rows=136067680 width=70)
                                       Filter: ((decile)::text = 'U'::text)
                                 ->  Index Only Scan using dish_previous_records_pkey on dish_previous_records c  (cost=0.69..10414813.05 rows=101652024 width=33)
                           ->  Hash  (cost=6807.55..6807.55 rows=168555 width=23)
                                 ->  Seq Scan on apt_adhoc_dish_src_table_aamir b  (cost=0.00..6807.55 rows=168555 width=23)
(14 rows)
```

*Note*: All columns which are in where clause has index.

ServerInfo

[image]

Comment: Could you please share the results from explain (analyze, verbose, buffers) ?

Comment: Try using  a NOT EXISTS condition instead of the `LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL` approach

Comment: Is it required to sort in random order? If not try removing the `order by` clause

Comment: I don't think that that plan was produced from that query.  Where did the filter on decile come from?

Comment: @jjanes, Plan was produced from the same query. While pasting the query filter was removed. You can ignore.

Comment: @long_hair_programmer,

We can't ignore order by clause as I need records to be picked up randomly.